# По каким правилам осуществляется расстановка знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

По каким правилам пишется данное предложение? Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

**Энтони Хопкинс не снимается в плохих в фильмах(,) и «Молчание Ягнят» (—) тому доказательство.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Корректно:

> Энтони Хопкинс не снимается в плохих в фильмах**,**  и «Молчание **я**гнят» (—) тому доказательство.

1. Запятая ставится между частями сложносочиненного предложения.
2. В названиях из двух и более слов с прописной буквы пишется только первое.
3. Если перед сказуемым стоит относящийся к нему второстепенный член предложения, то тире **обычно** не ставится. Вот некоторые примеры, где тире поставлено: *«12» и последующее ― тому доказательство*  [Давид Самойлов. Памятные записки (1971-1990)], *Мои письма ― тому доказательство…* [Георгий Гачев. Господин Восхищение (Повесть об отце) // Библиотека «Огонек», 1989].

Comment: По поводу третьего пункта. У Розенталя написано, что "если перед сказуемым стоит относящийся к нему второстепенный член предложения, то тире обычно не ставится" : Степан нам сосед (Ш.); Коля мне друг. У лопатина: тире не ставится "если между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица: Мой отец для меня друг и наставник.

Comment: @Стася да, вы правы, есть такое. Однако нередко тире все-таки ставится: "Мой муж ― яркое тому доказательство. Вот буквально вчера он улетел в командировку". [Маша Трауб. Отец хоть куда // «Огонек», 2014],  "Выставка в Тюбингене ― очередное тому доказательство"[Аркадий Ипполитов. Открылась выставка в Тюбингене (1996) // «Коммерсантъ-Daily», 1996.01.27]. Я дополню ответ. Спасибо!

Comment: То есть, получается, что данное тире интонационное? Ставится на усмотрение автора?

Comment: @Стася думаю, да.